# Atomエディタで本文１行目をタブに表示したい

Tags: atom-editor

AtomエディタでSublimeTextのように、自動で本文１行目をタブに表示し、保存の際に表示されている文の名前で保存することは可能でしょうか。また、設定方法やパッケージ、プラグイン等ありましたらご教示いただけますでしょうか。

SublimeTextを使用していた際に、この機能を重宝しており、Atomエディタでも使用したいと考えています。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

稚作ですが、Atomパッケージを自分で作成してみたところ完成しました。

パッケージ名は「[show-first-line-on-tab](https://atom.io/packages/show-first-line-on-tab)」です。

良かったら試してみてください。

Answer (score 1):

完全ではありませんがちょっと作ってみました。
http://qiita.com/nobuhito/items/5219173cf179754a4113

分割したあとの動きに不満がありますが。

Comment: サトウノブヒトさん、スクリプト作成、およびご回答頂きありがとうございます。
試してみましたところ、タブ表示部分(Pane分割部分以外)がいい感じでした。

実は、私もあれから稚作ですが、Atomパッケージを作成してみました。
次の回答に作成したパッケージのURLを載せます。